# Using AVAudioPlayer similar to Apple's avTouch project

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to replicate some of the functionality in Apple's avTouch, but I can't get `AVAudioPlayer` to play a track.

It logs `Could not play (null)`. The (null) represents AVAudioplayer `player.url`. However, when I log `player.url`, it returns correctly. I have also tested the stream URL (it's from soundcloud).

I have pretty much only made two changes from the sample code.

1. I'm using an audio stream URL, rather than a file.
2. I had to  add `__bridge` in the following code (I don't really know what it is for though)

   ```
   OSStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
     if (result)
   NSLog(@"Error initializing audio session! %@", result);

     [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
     NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
     [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
     if (setCategoryError)
       NSLog(@"Error setting category! %@", setCategoryError);

       result = AudioSessionAddPropertyListener (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, RouteChangeListener, (__bridge void *)self);
      if (result) 
   NSLog(@"Could not add property listener! %@", result);

   void RouteChangeListener(   void *                  inClientData,
                    AudioSessionPropertyID inID,
                    UInt32                  inDataSize,
                    const void *            inData)
   {
   SongsViewController* This = (__bridge SongsViewController*)inClientData;

   if (inID == kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) {

   CFDictionaryRef routeDict = (CFDictionaryRef)inData;
   NSNumber* reasonValue = (__bridge NSNumber*)CFDictionaryGetValue(routeDict, CFSTR(kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason));

   int reason = [reasonValue intValue];

   if (reason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable) {

       [This pausePlaybackForPlayer:This.player];
     }
    }
   }
   ```

**Edit**: I think this is occurring b/c `AVAudioPlayer` is not meant for network streams. Can I simply change AVAudioPlayer to AVPLayer? I have a feeling it's not that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer is not meant for network streams. Apple docs:

`Apple recommends that you use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O latency.`